# Spring Batch difference between pageSize and commit-interval

Tags: spring-batch

Whats the relationship/difference between Spring-Batch Reader 'pageSize' property and Writer 'commit-interval'.

I may be wrong but I see a pattern in my application that for every pageSize exceeded I get see one commit being made. Is this true.?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `commit-interval` defines how many items are processed within a single chunk.  That number of items are read, processed, then written within the scope of a single transaction (skip/retry semantics not withstanding).

The `page-size` attribute on the paging `ItemReader` implementations (`JdbcPagingItemReader` for example) defines how many records are fetched per read of the underlying resource.  So in the JDBC example, it's how many records are requested with a single hit to the DB.

While there is no direct correlation between the two attributes, it's typically considered a good idea to make them match, however they independently provide two knobs you can turn to modify the performance of your application.

With regards to your direct question, if you have the `page-size` set to the same as the `commit-interval`, then yes, I'd expect a single commit for each page.

Comment: Is commit-interval and chunk size are same?

Answer (score 4):

Commit interval determines how many items will be processed in a Chunk.

Page size determines how many items will be fetched every time it is needed.

Depending on the numbers you set, the behavior may be the one you describe. They are used for optimization.

Comment: How can we get the value of Commit Interval in writer ?